# Website that pays for writing fairly

Tags: publishing, self-publishing, publisher, websites

About a month ago, I stumbled upon a website that claims to pay writers fairly and transparently out of advertising revenue. For the life of me, I cannot remember the name of the site, and after trawling through my internet history and various Google searches, I cannot find it again.

They had a distinctive yellow website identity, and I think the name started with 'D' -- something like 'Discourse' or 'Discursive'. They seemed to be a new outfit, intent on disrupting online publishing norms.

I know this is nearly nothing to go on, but I am at my wit's end. Please help me, hive mind: is anyone familiar with the site I'm talking about?

Comment: Maybe try ctrl(or command if you have that)+h and check you internet history. this sounds like a scam site though, but if you find it pls post it.

Comment: I have both searched my history and checked it line-by-line manually.

Comment: huh. well, its a REALLY long shot seeing as it was a month ago, but maybe ctrl+shift+t over and over? this will open closed tabs, and it will probably take a long time to get to a month ago, and if it wasn't in your search history idk if it would show up. probably not a very good option, but im searching the interwebs looking for your site. might get lucky and find it.

Comment: if you remember anything, from a bit of text to a picture to the shape of an ad on the page, please edit it into your question, the more details the easier to find. thanks.

Comment: do you remember what type of writing the site was for? general fiction? scifi? technology tutorials?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It was for short non-fiction, very similar to the style of pieces you might get on Medium. I wish I had more to tell you; I've wasted virtually the whole day trying to find the damn site...

Answer (score 1):

So far have found 2 sites that match the description, although I doubt either of them are the one you're looking for.

- [DistanceWeb](http://distanceweb.net/about_join.shtml) which has a vaguely yellow theme and starts with a D
- [nDash](https://www.ndash.com/) which is also a vaguely yellow theme and has a D.

If I find more I will edit them in below;

- nothing else yet sorry :(

Comment: Unfortunately not these, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for bothering everyone -- I found it! It's called Discourse Blog.

https://discourseblog.com/turning-the-page/

It is a left-leaning writing cooperative that seeks to remunerate their contributors fairly. There is also Defector, a sports website with a similar ethos.

Now that I've spent 4+ hours scouring the Internet, I'm going to see what it's like outside...